# Mvn compile before exec

Tags: maven, compilation, exec, phase

I am trying to set up my POM such that when I do `mvn exec:exec` or `mvn exec:java` it will first compile the source and iff successful, execute it.

I have the following and have tried moving the `<execution>` part about but can't get it to work:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>exec</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>my.main.class</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

When I do either `mvn exec:exec ...` or `mvn exec:java` it doesn't first compile. I have tried putting the `<execution>` part in the `exec` plugin section but that didn't work either?

Comment: Why not run "compiler:compile" before your exec:exec/exec:java?

Comment: @Elad I keep forgetting to compile and then get confused why nothing has changed.

Comment: @Lerp Facing the same issue, have you found a solution?

Comment: It seems not possible, maybe this is not the right "maven" way :/

Comment: "exec" is not a phase, which is why you can't bind the compile plugin to it

Answer (score 4):

It's an old topic, but someone else might be interested in an alternative solution for this.

It's not exactly what you were looking for, but you can compile and execute using a single command:

```
mvn compile exec:exec
```

This way *Maven* will always compile the project before executing it.

Answer (score 2):

You can bind the exec plugin to a phase following `compile` in [build lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) (`verify` in the example below):

```
<profile>
    <id>proxy</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                           <mainClass>my.main.class</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

and than run `mvn verify`.

I see the answer is very late and you may have found a solution.
I'm just leaving as a reference for others who may need it.

Comment: Thanks for this but, if I'm understanding correctly, the OP is trying to have compilation occur during the [direct] execution of `mvn exec:[exec|java]` and **not** as part of a 'normal' Maven build cycle. To clarify, they, as I, want the code to to be built first when we run 'mvn exec' but do **not** want 'exec' to be run during normal Maven build cycles/phases.

Answer (score 1):

This will not quite answer the question but it will help us to accomplish the main objective you have.

Instead of executing a `build` goal when running the `mvn exec:java` we can execute the `mvn exec:java` when calling a 'post-build" phase/goal.

This will effectively make that phase unusable as it was because we will be substituting it by the execution but if we have a "post-build" goal that we are not using (like `package` or `install`) we can use it for the execution like so:
using package goal will end up like:

```
...
    <properties>
        ...
        <main.class>${project.groupId}.MainClass</main.class>
        ...
    </properties>
...
    <build>
        <plugins>
...
            <!-- region Forces the app to be executed when using mvn package -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- endregion -->
...
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

This way when we execute goal `package` with: `mvn package` the plugin will be executed and the application runned.